# Xcode 9 GM undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, xcode9

In Xcode 9's GM release, I am getting some compile-time errors for `undefined symbols for architecture arm64`, namely for AVFoundation with:

- `AVCapturePhotoOutput().supportedFlashModes`
- `AVCapturePhotoSettings().availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`

In both cases, using their "undocumented" `__supportedFlashModes`/`__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` builds just fine.

1. Has anybody encountered the same issues in other frameworks?
2. [API does not document such breaking changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings?changes=latest_minor), is this a bug?

Comment: `supportedFlashModes` never worked stable. Obviously, they're moving it to KVO where it should be. Hopefully, they fixed other issues related to `AVFoundation`, loads of crashes, you know

Comment: Facing the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were "inadvertently" marked private. Should be reverted with next release I guess?
Workaround above is recommended by Apple.

[Official response](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810)